# How to access the Keyboard Layout Options in 13.10+

Tags: keyboard-layout

In 13.04 or below I only needed to access the keyboard layout and then click on the Options button as seen in the image below:

[image]

In 13.10 the Options button is missing as seen in the following image:

[image]

So what is the new method to access any and all Keyboard Layout Options. In my case I wish to activate 3 of them, from killing X, to some custom keys.

Comment: This a bug on Ubuntu 13.10 [Can't set keyboard layout change to alt+shift, ctrl+shift, etc.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322)

Comment: The bug report is about an issue with the key combination to change the keyboard layout (e.g. between English and French) and a fix has already been released in "proposed". The rest of the options can now be changed in gnome-tweak-tool. It doesn't look like the layout options dialog is going to come back, so you can reopen this question.

Comment: @Joni Thanks for clarifying this. Will wait 24 hours for more information regarding this issue. If I see other issues have been solved I will reopen to see if somebody knows of a change in the behavior.

Comment: @luis-alvardado You can also use dconf-editor for the other settings, which I just put in an answer to [Switch caps lock](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc/365701#365701)

Comment: @chaskes setting switch key using gnome-tweak-tool does not work in Ubuntu 13.10, it is handled by some app (that even steals focus when shortcut is pressed).

Comment: @kolen My answer does not mention the tweak tool, but dconf-editor, which is different. I also say that the _keyboard switching settings do not work_ right now because of the bug. My answer is about the _other_ settings that are no longer available through system settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's what GNOME developers decided. Instead, you can access equivalent setting menu in **gnome-tweak-tool**.

Try install gnome-tweak-tool in official repository and go to **typing** section.

Comment: Well, I had gnome-tweak-tool already in 13.04 and it was upgraded. *HOWEVER* when starting it quickly pops up its window and then segfaults.     Tried   sudo reinstall gnome-tweak-tool  which did the reinstall alright,  but it still segfaults....    Really a pain I do need to write in German regularly but am using an "En" (US) keyboard all the time for reasonable programming....  Now I'm really severely handicapped with ubuntu 13.10 as opposed to 13.04 and earlier:  I definitely want to get  "R-Alt" (Alt to the right of space bar) to work as temporary switch to the (Swiss) German kbd layout!

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool   from the terminal emits the following: WARNING : Shell not installed or running
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.nautilus.desktop (key computer-icon-visible)
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_shell_extensions.py", line 199, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
WARNING: Shell not running
None
INFO   : GSettings missing key org.gnome.mutter (key workspaces-only-on-primary)

Answer (score 11):

It seems that this is by design; there has been a reorganization of the keyboard/input methods. Now the keyboard configuration is accessed by system settings -> keyboard, tab shortcut, Typing entries:

[image: keyboard typing shortcuts]

But quite a lot of options is just not here anymore, like the settings for ctrl-alt-backspace.

There is now a specific issue opened in Launchpad to ask that back: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1245064

By the way, on Nov. 2, 2013, there are still quite a handful of bugs with the change, which you can explore with the quite long and detailed list of related bug linked in the description of the issue aforementioned.

Comment: That's the window I get, but the entry with Compose Key says "disabled" and I can't find a way to enable it.

Comment: @Christine I have just Xubuntu available now, but you should be able to select the whole line with Compose and then clicking on "Disabled" you should have a menu with the possible Compose Key(s).

Comment: @Rmano On Ubuntu I do not have the entries *"Switch to next/previous input source"*!?

Answer (score 11):

It's still possible to make the change from the command line using dpkg. Credit goes to this site: http://www.humans-enabled.com/2013/10/ubuntu-1310-enable-controlaltbackspace.html.
To sum up what's written there, you can open a terminal and enter

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

This will take you through a series of options for the keyboard; for the first 4 or 5 just hit enter to keep things as is, and you'll end up with the option to enable Ctrl-Alt-Backspace.

Comment: This was helpful - I used it to remove the ctrl / caps lock swapping that I'd set up but couldn't access any longer. Even though it didn't ask me about that particular config, it did appear to clean it out.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the "Keyboard" and delete all languages  except the language you want.
Save the changes.
Th eproblem should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut key to switch back to the US keyboard source.  In *System Settings > Keyboard*, select the *Shortcuts* tab, then select *Typing*.  Try pressing the key combination shown as *Switch to previous source* or *Switch to next source*.

I bet that Tor M's solution would have the same effect.

I discovered this because I installed Japanese language and intentionally switched to Japanese.  Then I recognized that the punctuation symbols moved to their locations on a Japanese keyboard.  So I just used the keyboard shortcut again to switch back to the US English keyboard.