# Switch language shortcut bug [ubuntu 14.04 Gnome]

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts, language-support

I use 2 languages: english and russian.

Languages ​​normally switched on using the taskbar

When using the keyboard shortcut icon changes its notation to another language BUT the language set does not change.

How fix this problem?

Comment: Some combination has problem, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 and also http://askubuntu.com/questions/360378/how-to-access-the-keyboard-layout-options-in-13-10

Comment: I have a similar problem having upgraded 12.04 to 14.04. The ibus keyboard language switcher stopped working. Because I work between English and Chinese this is a big problem. The weird thing is the indicator changes language, but the text typed stays solidly in English. I have even tried installing a different language engine (fcitx), nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Systems Settings* -> *Text Entry* -> under *Input sources to use:* click Russian. Then click the little keyboard icon to open the **Russian** window and display the Russian keyboard layout. Is the Russian keyboard layout displayed in the Russian window? If the Russian keyboard layout isn't displayed in the Russian window, you can add it by clicking on the plus button (**+**) to open the **Choose an input source** window, selecting the Russian language from the list of keyboard input languages, and then clicking the **Add** button to add the Russian keyboard layout.

[image]

If this doesn't work, then there is another possibility. Did the Panel language switcher icon work properly in the beginning? If so, did you ever have boot problems with your computer and then used the `startx` command to start the X.Org X Window System?

Comment: My problem is similar, but with Chinese (see my comment on the OP). Language and input methods appear to have been installed, but cannot be used because the switcher fails to switch the language, in spite of changing the language flag on the icon.

Comment: @Bobble I wrote a bash script to do keyboard layout switching, including a graphical interface and it's still on an old computer which I haven't used in a long time. My bash script uses setxkbmap and has 9menu as a dependency. Leave another comment if you want me to drag my old computer out of storage and upload my bash script to Ubuntu Pastebin. The locale code of the Chinese language is cn and English is en.

Comment: there is some discussion of using setxkbmap [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity) but it looks like this, too, is a sub-optimal solution. But thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the same problem which worked on Gnome 15.04 is a workaround from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1437411). So on 14.04 use at your own risk:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Alt>Shift_R']"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Text Entry click under the "Switch to next source using" and then type the shortcut that you want. It will be recognised automatically (in my case Alt+Shift L).

Comment: For me this does not address the central problem: the shortcut keys only seem to change the indicator, without actually changing the language.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active true
```

or you can find this setting in `dconf-editor`

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I use English(US) and Rassian) Super+Space combination changes indicator but not the language in GEdit and Firefox. At the same time Skype accepts different languages.
 Changing to Alt+Shift and reverse combination to Control+Shift helps me.
 Now GEdit and Skype, and Firefox recognizes language input right.