# Gnome3 Can't change keyboard layout

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, 14.10

I'm norwegian so I have the norwegian keyboard as default, but now I need to write something in spanish, so I added the spanish keyboard layout. However, when I try to change between them the label in the toolbar changes, but I'm still typeing in norwegian. It only works if I remove the norwegian layout from the list, but if I then try to add it again I have to remove the spanish layout to get it to work. As I am switching between them all the time this becomes rather tedious. As far as I remember it worked fine before I installed Gnome3, but it's a long time ago. Is this a bug in Ubuntu or just Gnome? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you changing between layouts?

Comment: I've tried using the menu in the toolbar and by using the shortcut Super + Space. They both behave the same way.

Comment: I think it's a bug in Ubuntu introduced between 12.04 and 14.04. See the responses to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/458009/switch-language-shortcut-bug-ubuntu-14-04-gnome). I have seen this discussed in a number of forums, but so far no solution.

Comment: @Bobble Yes, that looks the same. I also tested it in Arch with Gnome, and a different installation of Ubuntu with just unity installed, and it worked fine for both. So is it a Ubuntu+Gnome problem, or did I just mess something up?

Comment: I don't think it is Gnome, because I looked at Debian Wheezy (Gnome 3.4.2) and Ibus seems to behave well there. From what I have read (sorry, can't find all the refs, but at least a couple were on Launchpad) other flavours of Ubuntu (Lubuntu in particular) are also affected. I am continuing to investigate, even jumping ship to BSD to find something that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it just started to work, but I don't know why. The only thing I've done that might have fixed it was updating the system, but it might be something else entirely, so I can't give any advice to people in the same situation.